# version range in jBoss Drools ReleaseId

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, drools, versioning

In my code I am specifying the release id of the kieJar as follows :

```
ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId("com.myapp", "myjar", "1.0.0");
KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kContainer );
// Start the KieScanner polling the Maven repository in provided time
kScanner.start( 10000l);
```

I read in drools book (Mastering drools 6) that If we specify version as "1.0.0"
and next version i.e. 1.0.1 is deployed in maven then KieScanner automatically updates the KieBase. I tried that But it didn't work. I tried "LATEST" and "RELEASE" also but I saw that maven 3 has dropped them. I am creating my kieJar using below GAV. I have tried to use "inclusive" and "exclusive" range also i.e.
[1.0.0,) but It didn't work.

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

I have used below link as reference : [Mastering jBoss drools 6](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CZnjCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=version%20range%20in%20drools&source=bl&ots=NJ2p8xIADt&sig=FEB8XlAro0KedtarNyHpKz3WKhw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV2KWLs6bPAhXBMY8KHYokDPUQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=version%20range%20in%20drools&f=false)

My guess is version range should work in "ReleaseId" BUT Do I Need to make any changes in my POM.xml also while generating KieJar ? OR  How can I specify kieJar version only once in my code and If there is any version upgrade in kieJar , KieScanner should automatically update. Please help me.

Comment: What about `[1.0.0,)` ? But I can't recommend it...better is to define a clear version instead of a version range.

Comment: You should also explicitly write down what `doesn't work` means? Failure etc. error message etc. log output ?

Comment: It says artifact with this "[1.0.0,)"  version is not present.

Comment: So you don't have such version available in your repository (repo manager?)

Comment: @khmarbaise I have already mentioned in the question the GAV that I have used to create my JAR. Do I need to change anything else for version range ?